# Laravel 5.8 routing issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.8

I freshly installed Laravel 5.8 and have a routing issue where I can't give a URL and name it whatever I want.

```php
Route::get('profile/my-profile', [
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@profile',
    'as' => 'profile'
]);
```

I tried the above, and the result is when I wrote like this, it doesn't show my profile picture in the browser. It only shows my name but when I wrote it like the following, it's okay.

```php
Route::get('profile', [
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@profile',
    'as' => 'profile'
]);
```

Comment: So, what's the problem exactly? *"I can't give a url name whatever I want"* or *"don't show my profile picture in browser"*?

Comment: I also want my profile picture beside my name, I used `{{ Auth::user()->profile_picture }}` actually after base path I can use one word like 'profile', if i use 'profile/something' it dosn't show my profile picture, how can I solve this problem?   @Tarasovych

Comment: @Tarasovych Thanks for commenting brother I solve this problem, by use `{{ asset(Auth::user()->profile_picture) }}` now I can give url name whatever I want, if we don't use `asset()` then we have to write a url like this `Route::get('profile', [
   'uses' => 'ProfileController@profile',
   'as'   => 'profile'
]);` and if we use `asset()` then we can use url name whatever we want like `Route::get('profile/blah/blah', [
   'uses' => 'ProfileController@profile',
   'as'   => 'profile'
]);`. **Happy Coding**..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine....

```
{{ asset(Auth::user()->profile_picture) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this type of routing and it's fine and I have no error

```
http://yoursite.com/profile/myprofile

Route::group(['prefix' => 'profile'], function (){
     Route::get('/myprofile', [
        'uses' => 'ProfileController@profile',
        'as' => 'pages.profile'
     ]);
});

or:

http://yoursite.com/myprofile

Route::get('/myprofile', [
   'uses' => 'ProfileController@profile',
   'as' => 'pages.profile'
]);

{{ route('pages.profile') }}
```

for the image or any file you want to attach use this code:

```
{{ URL::to('your file path') }}
```